# Use torch.where() to a batch of arrays

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using pytorch and I want to apply a simple torch.where(array > 0) to a batch of arrays without using a loop, how could I do this code using torch functions?

```
def batch_node_indices(states_batch):
    batch_indices = []
    for state in states_batch:
        node_indices = torch.where(state > 0)[0].detach().cpu().numpy()
        batch_indices.append(node_indices)
    return batch_indices
```

I tried different torch functions but I wasn't successful. I want the method to return a batch of arrays that each array contains the indices where the state array is bigger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "batch of indices"?

The problem with something like `torch.where(condition)` is each item in the batch has a different number of elements where `condition=True`. This means you can't have a batch-wise application of `where`, given that the outputs for each item in the batch will be of different size.

The default behavior of `where` is to put out a tuple of tensors, one for each axis, showing all the index tuples where `condition=True`. The output indices are flattened to deal with the irregular size issues. You use the outputs to get indices by batch if needed.

```py
x = torch.randn(16, 32, 64)
indices = torch.where(x>0)
print(indices)
> (tensor([ 0,  0,  0,  ..., 15, 15, 15]),
>  tensor([ 0,  0,  0,  ..., 31, 31, 31]),
>  tensor([ 4,  5,  7,  ..., 61, 62, 63]))

index_tensor = torch.stack(indices)
# for example, select outputs from the first item in the batch
index_tensor[:, index_tensor[0] == 0]
```

You can also use additional arguments in `torch.where` to return a tensor the same shape as the input. For example

```py
x = torch.randn(16, 32, 64)
x1 = torch.where(x>0, 1, 0) # fills 1 where x>0, 0 elsewhere

# shape is retained 
x.shape == x1.shape
> True

x2 = torch.where(x>0, x, float('-inf')) # returns `x` with -inf where x<0
```